# \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http() and filerenameupload

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use the 'filerenameupload' filter with \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http():

```
    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();

    $adapter->addFilter('filerenameupload', array(
        'target' => BASE_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
        'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'gallery' .
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'image.jpg',
        'randomize' => true,
    ));

    var_dump($adapter->isValid()); // true

    if (!$adapter->receive()) {
        $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
        echo implode("\n", $messages);
    }
```

Always having the error,

> File '/tmp/somefile.png' could not be renamed. An error occurred while processing the file.

/tmp/somefile.png  - exists, is readable an writable, distention folder too is readable an writable

Error comes from class RenameUpload:

```
protected function moveUploadedFile($sourceFile, $targetFile)
{
    ErrorHandler::start();
    $result = move_uploaded_file($sourceFile, $targetFile);
    $warningException = ErrorHandler::stop();
    if (!$result || null !== $warningException) {
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException(
        sprintf("File '%s' could not be renamed. An error occurred while processing the file.", $sourceFile), 0, $warningException
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

So maybe someone have an example or know how to fix this error? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @hemangpatel from #zftalk for advice, so the working action looks like:

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();

    $adapter->setDestination(BASE_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
            'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'gallery' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // Returns all known internal file information

    $adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $adapter->getDestination() .
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . rand(2, 10) . '.jpeg',
        'overwrite' => true));

    if (!$adapter->receive()) {
        $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
        return new ViewModel(['messages' => $messages]);
    } else {
        $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Upload success');

        $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin', ['controller' => 'gallery',
            'action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```